# Bigquery need to check for the existence of a set of values in one column in one set of tables and not in the other set of tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Three table has a column with, for example, names.  Need to know which names do not exist in the other three tables.  Need to do this as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from table1, table2, table3
where name not in (select name from other1, other2, other3)
```